# Advantages of using named intents over classes when creating intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I was poking around the [Github Android App](https://github.com/github/android) today and I noticed that rather than creating intents by calling `newActivity.class`, they have decided to create an intent-filter for each activity and then create intents by passing in that particular name to the new intent.  This got me thinking: are there any advantages to using this method, or is it simply a matter of style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage is that third party apps could, conceivably, directly invoke those activities -- the Android equivalent of "deep linking". This assumes that GitHub plans on documenting and supporting those `Intent` structure.

Then again, based on a casual inspection of that manifest, I would not be using the GitHub app as an example of strong Android programming practices. For example, there is no reason a GitHub client would need to override default configuration-change handling, and even if there is a reason, they are doing it wrong (only handling a subset of changes, rather than none or all).

Comment: Are you specifically referencing how they choose to "handle" screen rotation by just treating orientation and screenSize as configuration changes, or is there something else that I'm not seeing there?

Comment: @Jonathan: "by just treating orientation and screenSize as configuration changes" -- yes. First, that's a technique of last resort, and there are many better approaches. Second, since they do not cover *every* configuration change, their app will break when, say, the user changes language, or puts the device in a desk dock. And if the app *doesn't* break for things like locale and dock, then they didn't need the `android:configChanges` in the first place, as their app probably would handle rotation just fine.